# ActiveModelSerializer: return object of nils if association does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

Is it possible to have a serializer return an association of nils if no associated record exists?

e.g.

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :article

  def article
    # does not actually work
    super if super.present?

    Article.new
  end
end
```

This would allow something like the following to run without error, regardless of article presence:

```
# javascript
comment.article.published_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
def article
  object.article || Article.new
end
```